# Rails 3 - w jQuery - Global Loading Event?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

is there a Rails 3 jQuery global loading event?

I'd like to display a LOADING banner anytime jQuery is AJAX loading... and remove it when it's done...

Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For global do this :

```
$("#loading").bind("ajaxSend", function(){
  $(this).show();
}).bind("ajaxComplete", function(){
  $(this).hide();
});
```

For individual do this :

```
$.ajax({type: "GET",
        beforeSend: function() { $.globalThrobberStart    },
        complete: function() { $.globalThrobberStop     }
        ...
```

See more here : http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events